# Bertini's Theorem induces holomorphic mapping

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm learning Bertini's Theorem via the famous book by Griffiths and Harris.

In the page 138 they say that, if the linear system(over manifold $M$) we consider is just a pencil $\{D_{\lambda}\}, \lambda \in \mathbb{P}^1$ w.r.t. a divisor $D$. Then Bertini's Theorem gives a map:

$h: M-B\to \mathbb{P}^1$.

Here $B$ the base locus of given pencil. More explicitly, the map is given by the following rule:
if we identify the elements in pencil as linear space of holomorphic section of bundle $[D]$, we pick two basis $s_1, s_2$ of this linear space, then  for any $p\in M$, we can locally write $s_1, s_2$ as function $f, g$, thus there is a unique $\lambda\in \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $(f+\lambda g)(p)=0$, finally we map $p$ to $\lambda$.

Griffiths and Harris say that this map is holomorphic. If $\lambda$ is a generic element in $\mathbb{P}^1$, for point in $h^{-1}(\lambda)$, I can prove it's true by implicit function theorem , however this strategy fails if $\lambda$ is not a regular value, I try to use Hartogs extension theorem, but  I'm not sure if the holomorphic map I obtain by extension coincides with the original function.

Moreover, I find that if we consider higher-dimensional linear system, for each $p\in M$, the correspondent $\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^n$ may not unique, so I wonder if this map have an analogy in higher dimension.

Thanks you for your answer!

Comment: Hint: If $g\neq 0$, then $\lambda = -\frac{f}{g}$. If $f\neq 0$, then $\frac{1}{\lambda}=-\frac{g}{f}$. Now since $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic sections of a line bundle...

Comment: @KReiser Could you explain more explicitly? I can not understand your strategy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the subset of $M$ where $g\neq 0$, the quotient $f/g$ is a holomorphic function because $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic sections of a line bundle, and from our equation for $\lambda$ we find $\lambda = -\frac{f}{g}$ there. On the subset of $M$ where $f\neq 0$, the quotient $g/f$ is a homolorphic function for the same reason, and we find that $\frac{1}{\lambda} = -\frac{g}{f}$ there. Therefore we've shown that the map $h$ is holomorphic on $M\setminus B$.

To generalize to higher-dimensional linear systems (i.e. not a pencil), the map is from $M\setminus B$ to the projectivization of the global sections of the linear system. The proof that this is holomorphic is essentially the same as above: on the affine patch of the target projective space corresponding to the nonvanishing of some section, the local coordinates of the map are ratios of holomorphic sections of your line bundle where the denominator does not vanish. Therefore the coordinates are holomorphic, and the map is holomorphic.

Comment: But is the map in higher dimension well-defined? For the case $\mathbb{P}^2$, suppose our sections locally are holomorphic functions $f_1, f_2, f_3$, at $p$ we have $a_1f_1+a_2f_2+a_3f_3=0$, for convenience suppose none of $a_i, f_i$ euqal to $0$, then fix $a_1$, there are plenty of $a_2, a_3$ satisfy $a_2f_2+a_3f_3=-a_1f_1$.

Comment: That's not the right way to write down the map! The map is in general written down as follows: pick a basis $f_0,\cdots,f_n$ for the global sections of the linear system, and define a map from $M$ minus the common vanishing locus of all the $f_i$ to $\Bbb P^n$ by sending $p\in M$ to $[f_0(p):f_1(p):\cdots:f_n(p)]$. (This is equivalent to how you've written it in the $n=1$ case after a change of coordinates.)

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer!